# Nested CASE statement to exclude certain rows

Tags: sql, oracle10g, case

Sample Data: Oracle 10g

```
Number    Activity
1         x Activity
1         no activity
2         x activity
3         no activity
```

What I need to do is produce the rows where there is either no activity or x activity, then comes the problem: If there is an ID with both x activity and no activity, I only want to produce the x activity rows.  Can it be done?  Here is the `CASE` statement that produces the above data:

```
CASE WHEN DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL IS NULL
        THEN 'No Activity'
        ELSE DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL 
     END AS "Activity Type"
```

I am thinking I need to nest a `CASE` statement, but I can't quite gather the logic in my head.  Please let me know if there is anything that I can do to help.  Per the usual, I have not included the entire query here, as it is quite large, but will edit if anyone feels it is necessary.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By grouping by ID and filtering you might get through it:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN MAX(NVL(a.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL, 'aaaa')) = 'aaaa'
            THEN 'No Activity'
        ELSE a.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL
    END AS "Activity Type"
FROM DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE a
GROUP BY a.id
```

The problem is if you actually select other fields, it will probably break the `GROUP BY` and we'll have to make a subquery.

Comment: Thanks, that did work.  I am new-er to SQL and feel like I abuse the MAX() sometimes to eliminate duplicate rows, and am therefore hesitant to ever use it.  It looks like it is necessary in these cases.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `MAX()` around the case statement and than a `GROUP BY` on the ID field.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL IS NULL
        THEN 'No Activity'
        ELSE DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL 
     END) AS "Activity Type"


GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: JWK, I'm upvoting yours as well since we posted at the same time, for approx. the same answer.